# Multiline equation without number

Tags: equations

I am trying to have a multiline equation without any numbering, even not in the last one.

```
\begin{align}
a = x \nonumber \\
b = y
\end{align}
```

However, this is producing a line number in the last line, which would like not to happen.

I have also tried the `equation` and `equation*` environments with no luck.

Thanks.

P.S. What' the markup for rendering LaTeX code. Can't seem to be able to find it in the help page?

Comment: erh, `align*` should be obvious. There is no markup for rendering LaTeX code. Only source code

Comment: It might be a good to start reading the manual for the [`amsmath` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and browsing [tag:align].

Answer (score 51, accepted):

How about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for the "align" and "align*" environments
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} % the "starred" equation environments produce no equation numbers
a &= b\\  % if no alignment is needed, use the gather* instead of the align* env.
  &= c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If you do use the unstarred version, remember that `\nonumber` operates on only one line, so to omit numbers entirely, `\nonumber` (or `\notag`) must be input for every line.